# Usar querySelectorAll em um option quando existe mais de um Select

Tags: javascript, html

Bom dia galera, já de antemão tenham todos um ótimo feriado.

Estou com uma função em javascript que faz a contagem de uma lista assim:

```
let counting = document.querySelectorAll("option:checked");
```

No começo achei que tinha funcionado, mas via que quando limpava a lista, ainda na contagem sobravam 2 itens, que descobri ser de outros elementos `<select>` que existem na mesma página.

Tem como filtrar o querySelectorAll, por exemplo apenas contar as options, o select tenha uma id específica por exemplo?

Answer (score 1):

No final descobri que posso passar 2 parâmetros no querySelectorAll então agora minha variável ficou assim:

```
let counting = document.querySelectorAll("#selection option:checked");
```

Fica aí a resposta se alguém procurar pela mesma situação =]